# при отправке axios запроса на api сервер не прикрепляются куки

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

проблема возникла на МакБуке, делаю  GET  запрос на https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/auth/me , предварительно я вошёл под своей учёткой на этот сервер, но запрос все равно возвращает ответ, как если бы я не авторизовался, посмотрел в консоли наличие куков и оказалось, что они не идут с запросом, а вот на другом ноуте куки цепляются и ответ приходит корректный, почему на маке куки не идут с запросом не понимаю,

```
axios.get(`https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/auth/me`,{
        withCredentials: true,
        
        headers: {
            
                    "API-KEY": "b27fb751-498e-44a4-8886-19d91desf081"
                    
                    
                  }
        
    })
```

и вроде бы параметр wtihCredentials должен обеспечивать прикрепление куков, но они не цепляются к запросу и это только на маке такая проблема, на других компьютерах всё хорошо

Comment: прикрепите код пожалуйста, так ничего не понятно

Comment: возможно, отключено слежение за пользователем в настройках браузера. В этом случае куки полностью отключаются

Comment: оказывается проблема была в том, что в настройках была отключена опция ДЛЯ ЧТЕНИЯ для этого сервера, теперь всё работает